# Watchkit: Set global tint programmatically

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, tintcolor

I know how to set the global tint of the project from Storyboard. But how do I set the tint programmatically?

Apple's documentation goes as far to say:

> Every WatchKit app has an associated key color, which is applied to
>   the >following UI elements:
>
> -The title string in the status bar
>
> -The app name in short look notifications
>
> An app’s key color is stored in the Global Tint property of the app’s
>   storyboard. To access this property, select your storyboard and
>   display the File inspector. Select one of several preexisting colors
>   from the popup menu or use the color picker to specify a custom color.

But can it be done programmatically too?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it programmatically at this time. I would suggest you open an enhancement [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) in the Apple bug report system.

Comment: No (watchOS 4).

Comment: There should be an update on this, as starting with SwiftUI, there is no storyboard where one could set the global tint color.